# What causes the line patterns in the palm of the hand?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, skin

The line patterns on the hand are unique to each individual, but what causes these lines and re they advantageous in anyway?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 3):

The lines on the hand are known as [flexion creases](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/flexion+crease), and they exist because in their absence, the skin will stretch outwards when the palm is closed due to the decreased surface area of the closed palm, causing problems with gripping.

Developmental disorders such as Down Syndrome often cause there to be only one palm line, known as the [simian crease](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transverse_palmar_crease), as shown on the left.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think this answers the entire question that was posed by the OP.